# HTML divide and conquer

Tags: php, html, web

i am looking for the best pratice when it comes to HTML.

Now my normal programming instincts tells me to always divide and conquer but i am not sure how or even if it is recommended when it comes to `HTML`.

So say for example i have the following index file:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Dinner plans</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header top">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>

               <?php
               if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
                 echo "Du er logged ind";
               }else
                ?>

                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

          </div>

       </li>

    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <nav>
             <ul>

                  <li>

                  </li>

             </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

now i would devide some of this code for example the menu into another HTML file for instance `menu.html` and then place the content of the file within the index file.

My question is simple is this recommended and if so how is it achieved?

Comment: For PHP? Multiple files **only if** the are actually reusable. For that consider using either `include()` or `require()` as the situation dictates.

Comment: But is it recommended to divide and conq?

Comment: like....the algorithm?

Comment: how about you dig a bit into MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is if you can separate parts of an HTML page into smaller pages, so you can separate concerns.

In PHP this can be accomplished by referencing other files by a `require()` or `include()`. But I still don't believe this really answers your question. ASP.NET MVC allows you to render partial views within a webpage through `RenderPartial() but you didn't mention anything about using this.

You can find more at http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/how-do-i-work-with-data-in-aspnet-mvc-partial-views

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide a single webpage into multiple hmtl files you can do it by inserting frames. This is an old way of programming and you don't really see it these days but its efficient at doing what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is highly recommended. You are trying to apply the DRY principle (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). It's an excellent idea to apply this to your HTML. You can achieve this using require, require_once, include, and include_once in PHP. If you want to get a bit fancier, take a look at templating systems like Smarty (see: http://www.smarty.net/)